# Retrieving error response from html POST

Tags: .net, ios, xcode, soap

I am using this code to send a JSON to a .NET service to register a user:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                deviceID, @"DeviceId",
                                model, @"DeviceModel",
                                user, @"Username",
                                pass, @"Password",
                                email, @"email",
                                nil];

    NSDictionary *consumer = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:dictionary forKey:@"consumer"];
    NSLog(@"%@", consumer);

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:consumer
                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                         error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    NSString *urlString = @"http://aservice.co.uk/services/service.svc/RegisterConsumer";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError = NULL;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
    NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
    NSLog(@"%@", requestError);
```

This works fine as I receive back a JSON result of `{"RegisterConsumerResult":"True"}`

Now when I try to register a username that I know already exists, I get back the following HTML as the responseString:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">   <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>   </head>   <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.</p>
    </div>   </body> </html>
```

Obviously this isn't returning an actual error, just a web page telling me there was an error.
Have a missed a way to retrieve the actual error code from the service?
Is it possible that the service could be sending the error as a response somehow?

EDIT--
I forgot to mention, the actual errorResponse is nil, I'm assuming because HTML was returned that the actual request is classed as successful.

Comment: I think we'd need to see your asp.net code. How are you handling errors on your server?

Comment: I didn't write the server code unfortunately.

Comment: So an error is triggered by the response code. Check out this documentation for more on NSURLError https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes

Comment: How the server handles the error (what it returns) is the `requestError` in your case.

Comment: The requestError is nil which makes me think the request is appearing to be successful because HTML is being returned.

Comment: Well most likely the server is returning something that doesn't trigger one of those errors (because it's not a url error, it's a logical error from the server site) then, I suggest using `AFNetworking` and implementing the `AFJSONOperation` that way if it returns anything but JSON it will cause an error. PLUS AFNetoworking is bad ass and you won't regret using it.

Comment: Thanks mkral, I'll have a go of that.

Comment: Not going to have a chance to try AFJSONOperation until later, but just to add that i've seen the server logs and it returns a code 400 "Bad Request", but obviously my code is seeing a 200 as it gets a web page returned.

Comment: Well it doesn't mean that it's a 200 response just because there is HTML. I will post some code with how to do this in AFNetworking, also to check what the response is you need to cast your NSURLResponse to a NSHTTPURLResponse then it will have a `statusCode`instance method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, to check what the status code is so you can handle the >400 errors like so:

```
NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
NSError *requestError = NULL;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
NSUInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode];
//Then do your error checking.
```

If you want to use AFNetworking it can be pretty simple to do this, just add the library (find it here: http://afnetworking.com) then do it like this:

```
//NOTHING CHANGED TIL NEXT COMMENT
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            deviceID, @"DeviceId",
                            model, @"DeviceModel",
                            user, @"Username",
                            pass, @"Password",
                            email, @"email",
                            nil];

NSDictionary *consumer = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:dictionary forKey:@"consumer"];
NSLog(@"%@", consumer);

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:consumer
                                                   options:kNilOptions
                                                     error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", error);
//Start to use AFNetworking

    NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://aservice.co.uk/services/service.svc/"];
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:baseUrl];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"RegisterConsumer" parameters:dictionary];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"SUCESS");
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"FAILED WITH STATUS CODE %d - error description: %@", response.statusCode, error);
}];

[operation start];
```

This is using an asynchronous connection (you should!) then you can call your next step in the success block.

I didn't test this but it should work (or very close ) for what you need to do.

**Update**
Maybe you can use this code (I grabbed from [HERE](http://mobileorchard.com/accessing-http-headers-from-an-nsurlrequest/) ) to see what kind of data -- if any -- they are providing in the header and see if it's useful.

```
if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [response allHeaderFields];
    NSLog([dictionary description]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does give me the statusCode 400 which I can work with. I'm thinking the service might not actually send any helpful information as to why it failed but I think it might only send a 400 if the username already exists. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately you're at the mercy of the server here. Check my update to see if they are passing anymore info in the headers that might be useful to you.